# Regex: How to discard the last incomplete sentence?

Tags: regex

How do I do this in regex?

Discard the LAST sentence if it is incomplete (i.e. doesn't end with full stop, exclamation mark or question mark). Return the rest of the string. However, if the entire string has no ".", "!", or "?", return the same string back.

EXAMPLE 1:

"Bubble Tea originated in Taiwan in the early 1980's at a small tea stand. When adding flavor, the tea and flavoring needed to be shaken well for a good all around taste. This formed bubbles in"

should return

"Bubble Tea originated in Taiwan in the early 1980's at a small tea stand. When adding flavor, the tea and flavoring needed to be shaken well for a good all around taste."

EXAMPLE 2:

"Bubble Tea originated in Taiwan in the early 1980's at a small tea stand"

should return

"Bubble Tea originated in Taiwan in the early 1980's at a small tea stand"

Comment: What have you tried? create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match any sentence ending with `.`, `?` or `!` as well as sentences that do not include those characters:

```
(^.*[\.\?!]|^\S[^.\?!]*)
```

Test it here https://regex101.com/r/85UxdG/1